# MonoTouch.Dialog's OwnerDrawnElement highlight not working

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios

I am using MonoTouch.Dialog's OwnerDrawnElement, but it doesn't seem to allow the user to 'highlight' the cell when touching the screen. I've looked at the sample, but it doesn't show the highlighting. Any suggestions?

I noticed that TweetStation doesn't seem to user OwnerDrawnElement. Should I take another approach? I need to create a custom display cell much like TweetStation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OwnerDrawnElement was a contribution from the community, and it is not as sophisticated as it should be.   I would not depend on it for anything beyond the trivially basic.

I strongly recommend that you create your own Element, if you want to reuse some of the code for OwnerDrawElement, you could copy and paste that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll move to using my own Element. Oh, and thanks for Mono :)